# How to strip the basedir from an absolute path to get a relative path?

Tags: ant, relative-path

In the build.xml of my project I have a property defined:

```
<property name="somedir.dir" location="my_project/some_dir"/>
```

The value of `${somedir.dir}` will be an absolute path: `/home/myuser/my_project/some_dir`.

What I need is just the relative path `./my_project/some_dir` without the `${basedir}` value `/home/myuser`. How can I achieve this using Ant?

So far I found a solution by converting the property to a path and then use "pathconvert", but I don't think this is a nice solution:

```
<path id="temp.path">
    <pathelement location="${somedir.dir}" />
</path>
<pathconvert property="relative.dir" refid="temp.path">
    <globmapper from="${basedir}/*" to="./*" />
</pathconvert>
```

Any other (more elegant) suggestions?

Answer (score 44):

Since Ant 1.8.0 you can use the `relative` attribute of the Ant [`property` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) for this.

For example:

```
<property name="somedir.dir" location="my_project/some_dir"/>
<echo message="${somedir.dir}" />

<property name="somedir.rel" value="${somedir.dir}" relative="yes" />
<echo message="${somedir.rel}" />
```

Leads to:

```
 [echo] /home/.../stack_overflow/ant/my_project/some_dir
 [echo] my_project/some_dir
```

Comment: Note that the "basedir" attribute is very useful too as it allows to use another directory than the default base directory. Thank you for showing us this solution, it's a lot easier and more reliable than using a mapper with some regular expressions.

Answer (score 7):

A slightly less verbose solution would be specifying `somepath` inside `<pathconvert>`:

```
<pathconvert property="relative.dir">
  <path location="${somepath}"/>
  <globmapper from="${basedir}/*" to="./*" />
</pathconvert>
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use the Ant [`basename` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html). If you have:

```
<property name="somedir" value="/path/to/file/here" />
<basename file="${somedir}" property="somebasedir" />
<echo>${somebasedir}</echo>
```

The value that gets echoed is "here". It only seems to give you the final directory, which might not get enough of what you want.

Comment: this IS what I wanted... 4 years later.

Answer (score 1):

This was the approach that worked well for me in Windows, adapted from @Garns answer:

```
<path id="uploadFilePath">
    <fileset dir="${wcm.folderName}">
        <include name="*" />
        <exclude name="*.attr" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<pathconvert property="relFilelist">
    <path refid="uploadFilePath" />
    <mapper>
        <globmapper from="${wcm.folderName}/*" to="*" handledirsep="true" />
    </mapper>
</pathconvert>
```

I think that handledirsep="true" is pretty important in globmapper, it didn't work for me otherwise no matter how much I fiddled with forward/backslashes.  (I do all my slashes as forward in my ant scripts just so I can run them on unixy systems.)  My version of Ant is 1.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

`location` expands automatically the path using the project's `basedir`. So I think `value` option gives you a better control:

```
<property name="base.dir" value="/home/myuser"/>
```

and

```
<property name="somedir.dir" value="${base.dir}/some_dir"/>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I already have a given path "${base.dir}/some_dir" and I need to get the relative path "./some_dir".

Comment: Why do you need to extract `some_dir` when you have it into `${somedir.dir}`?

Comment: ${somedir.dir} would be something like "/home/blah/mydirectory"  and what the question is asking, is how to get just  "./mydirectory" from it. So you can't just use ${somedir.dir}.  In nant there are a bunch of functions built in like  path::get-directory-name  But I can't seem to find if those exist in Ant. I'm also in need of how to do this.

Comment: Yes. But as you can see, I'm using `value` instead of `location`. So, if you set `base.dir` to `/home/blah` and `somedir.dir` to `mydirectory`, you'll have them separately, and the absolute path will be `${base.dir}/${somedir.dir}`. Why compacting the absolute path into `base.dir` with the option location, and then looking for a way to extract the working directory from it?

Comment: true if you set the variable ourself, but what if it comes as an output of some other task ?